# MySQL SUM update over 4 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to ask for help with and UPDATE command, which depends on relation of 4 tables. (Or it is even possible?

theese are my tables:

```
Characters
guid, ...., totalItemlevel

template_items
id, ... itemlevel, ...,

instances_item
itemInstanceID, itemID, Owner
(itemID is foreign key template_items.id, Owner is foreign key Character.guid)

inventory_character
guid, slot, iteminstance
(guid is foreign key character.guid, item is foreign key instances_item.itemInstanceID)
```

Now I need to do an UPDATE script, that will set totalItemLevel as a sum of template_items.itemLevel, if the character has instance of that item in inventory with slot>20

In pseudo-statement:

```
UPDATE characters 
SET    totalItemLevel = SUM(FOR EACH ITEM IN INVENTORY(is slot>20?(GET its template(get itemLevel))));
```

So i tried something like this

```
SELECT  SUM(template_items.itemLevel) 
FROM    template_items, 
        inventory_character, 
        instances_item, 
        characters 
WHERE   chararacter.guid = inventory_character.guid 
AND     inventory_character.slot > 19 
AND     inventory_character.iteminstance = instances_item.itemInstanceID 
AND     instances_item.itemID = template_items.id);
```

This is definitely not working, it is crazy and it will probably need some subqueries, but I do really do not know, how to achieve this.

Also, there is no way I can do it in some other way like do some queries in PHP and then count it ... I need to do this update directly in the database.

So please, any ideas, how to achieve this calculated column?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to store computed values (from other columns.) Create a view instead.

Comment: In general, same issue, I need to do at least SELECT of that value per character. So If it was a View, it would be agan Characters.name and GS value as a new table(view) From that, I can do the update

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need slot > 20 (in your post you have slot > 20 in one place and slot > 19 in another):

```
UPDATE Characters
SET Characters.totalItemLevel = s FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(template_items.itemlevel) AS s, c.[guid]
    FROM Characters c
    INNER JOIN inventory_character ON inventory_character.[guid] = c.[guid]
    INNER JOIN instances_item ON instances_item.itemInstanceID = inventory_character.iteminstance AND instances_item.[Owner] = c.[guid]
    INNER JOIN template_items ON template_items.id = instances_item.itemID 
    WHERE c.[guid] = instances_item.[Owner] AND slot > 20
    GROUP BY c.[guid]
) A
WHERE Characters.[guid] = A.[guid]
```